# Add view from XIB to custom UINavigationBar subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uinavigationbar

I followed [this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js9oD.png) to create a taller UINavigationBar:

```
var heightIncrease: CGFloat = 38.0

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -heightIncrease)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var newSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    newSize.height += heightIncrease
    return newSize
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    for view in self.subviews {
        if (NSStringFromClass(view.classForCoder).containsString("UINavigationBarBackground")) {
            view.frame.origin.y = self.bounds.origin.y + heightIncrease - statusBarHeight
            view.frame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height + statusBarHeight
        }
    }
}

var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height
}
```

[image]

Now I want to add a view from an XIB to that bottom part. My first thought was to do something like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -heightIncrease)

    if let accessoryView = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .loadNibNamed("NavBarAccessoryView", owner: self, options: nil)
        .first as? NavBarAccessoryView {
            accessoryView.frame.size.width = self.bounds.size.width
            accessoryView.frame.origin.y = 75
            self.addSubview(accessoryView)
    }
}
```

It looks ok, but I can't select a segment in the segmented control, it's as if it were just a picture:

[image]

Is there a better way to do this? I'm sorry if it's a silly question or if my attempt makes no sense, I'm new at this and so far I've only dealt with views and stuff from the interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

i write extension :

```
extension UIView {

static func instanceFromNibByClassName()  -> UIView {
    let nibName = stringFromClass(self as AnyClass)
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: nil, options: nil).first! as! UIView
}
```

}

so i can get instance like this:

```
    var coverTableViewCell=YQEventCoverTableViewCell.instanceFromNibByClassName() as! YQEventCoverTableViewCell
```

Comment: Well, ok, but my main problem is adding it to the navigation bar.